# Open and close the pdf file that I built from raspberry pi with python

Tags: python, linux, pdf, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

When I run the program, the file does not open and does not make any error.
How I can fix it?

```
import subprocess, os, signal
from time import sleep
p = subprocess.Popen("/home/pi/Desktop/d.pdf", shell=True, 
preexec_fn=os.setsid)
sleep(5)
os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Open the pdf file in a PDF Viewer? Output it into the terminal?

Comment: Your code is *Python*, but you tagged your question with `openpdf`, which is a *Java* SDK. Does not compute. Are you really sure about your tag?

Comment: No I want open the pdf file in a qpdfview with python